# null object reference error in onCreate() method in Main Activity

Tags: java, android-fragments

While working with fragments, I received this error. I have looked around a lot, here, various tutorials and all, but I just can't seem to tell, where I have gone wrong... I know this question has been asked repeatedly and all, but help me out!

Thanks in Advance!
PS: Haven't posted a question before, so, Sorry in advance too!

1. Main Activity

   ```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       if(savedInstanceState==null)
       {
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,new MainActivityFragment()).commit();
       }

   }
   ```
2. Fragment Activity

   ```
      public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

          CalendarView cv;
          Context context;

          public MainActivityFragment() {
          }

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              //getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
          }

          @Override
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);



          EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
          editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
               getCalendarView();
              }
          });

          return view;
      }
   ```
3. MainActivity Layout

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.ipt02.spotchecktrial1.MainActivity"
   >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Is this coming?"/>



    <fragment
       android:id="@+id/fragment"
       class="com.example.ipt02.spotchecktrial1.MainActivityFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
4. And finally the logcat:

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.ipt02.spotchecktrial1/com.example.ipt02.spotchecktrial1.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
> 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object
> reference at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
> at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:176)
>                 at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3992)
>                 at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
>                 at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:493)
>                 at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:489)
>                 at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:485)
>                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:103)
>                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.<init>(PhoneWindow.java:2226)
>  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3316)
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3669)
>  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:368)
> at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
> at com.example.ipt02.spotchecktrial1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
> ```

**EDIT - ADDED Strings.XML file**

```
 <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
<string-array name="location">
    <item>Amsterdam</item>
    <item>Dubai</item>
    <item>Great Coral Reef</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="shift">
    <item>Shift - A</item>
    <item>Shift - B</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="disciples">
    <item>Sammy</item>
    <item>John</item>
    <item>Arry</item>
    <item>Voldy</item>
</string-array>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Ironman, i understand that it shows a NullPointerException, my doubt being why? I want the fragment to replace in the MainActivity, however that doesn't happen. Thus, the null pointer exception. So, how do i get around this?

Comment: can you post your res/string.xml file.
problem seems to be there..

Comment: @MithileshIzardar uploaded as you requested. I don't see any problem...

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` use this way

```
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("myFragmentTag");
    if (fragment == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragment =new MyFragment();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content,fragment,"myFragmentTag");
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```